# PRNG with output of constant length

Tags: algorithms, pseudo-random-generators

forgive me if my question is vaguely phrased.

I’m fishing around for a PRNG algorithm which generates numbers of a constant length, regardless of the seed.

I tried experimenting with a LCG but obviously the output for that is 0<=Xi+1<=m. Plus points if the algorithm is reversible (like you could get the seed back from a known output)

Comment: What is the *length of a number*? No leading zeroes? For $n$-bit numbers in a positional number system, say, base 7, just generate numbers from 0 to $(n-1)7^{n-1}$, add $7^{n-1}$ and be done?

Comment: @greybeard i was thinking that, but then will we be able to call it a PRNG?

Comment: @greybeard what i mean by constant length is that the output should always be, say 30 numbers in length. So no leading zeros

Comment: Please [edit] your question to state the requirements clearly.  Don't put clarifications in the comments.  And don't just append clarifications to the end of the question, but revise it so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Define what you mean by "length" before using that term.

Comment: @D.W. looking back at my question I feel i left a lot of things unexplained. I'll create a new question with the entire context.

Comment: asked a new question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/157832/creating-a-prng-to-replicate-the-library-of-babel)