# Creating a PRNG to replicate the LIbrary of Babel

Tags: algorithms, pseudo-random-generators

I had asked a question here about this before but it had a lot of vagueness to it, so I'll rephrase the entire thing.

I'm trying to create a PRNG that would replicate Borge's Library of Babel, i.e. 3200 characters made of 29 individual characters (26 alphabets, space, comma and period). Yes, I know libraryofbabel.info exists, and I admire it. I'm doing this as kind of a programming exercise for myself.

I had thought of the following approach: I generate a random number based on a seed that has a length of 6400 integers. Then I 'iterate' over the number, two numbers at a time and modulo them with 29, and map the remainder to a defined array with the 29 characters.

It later struck me that a the results of doing a modulo over a range 10-99 would not be equally distributed, and I was [right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkQ9P.jpg).

Do you guys have any insights on this, or is this just a futile attempt on my part?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: @Pseudonym hey, i went through the article but i cant understand how it connects to my problem

Comment: What you're asking for is a small program that generates a known sequence. This is a formally undecidable problem. Maybe the sequence has properties that can be exploited, but that's not in the question.